# =+ Operator in Java

Tags: java, math, operators

Consider this code:

```
long val = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 2; val++)
    val =+ ++i;

System.out.println(val);
```

**Why is `val = 3` in the end?**

I would have calculated like this:

```
val     i
0       0   i < 2 = true;
0       0   ++i;
0       1   val =+ 1;
1       1   (end of for loop) val++;
2       1   i < 2 = true;
2       1   ++i;
2       2   val =+ 2;
4       2   (end of for loop) val++;
5       2   i < 2 = false;
Output: 5
```

But it's 3. I don't understand why the increment `val =+ ++i` is not done the second time when `i = 1` and getting pre-incremented to `i = 2`.

Comment: Is it `=+` or `+=`?

Comment: That would be the difference between compiling and not compiling. ++ before or after `i`, post or pre increment is different too.

Comment: @clwhisk `=+ ++val` compiles just fine.

Comment: @AlexGoldstein `+=` does add to left argument. `=+` is `= +` is `=`.

Comment: ARGH thank you! I'm such an idiot for not seeing the obvious.

Comment: Gee, who thought letting that compile while treating it as two separate symbols was a good idea?

Comment: That's how to blow up rockets @clwhisk

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let's focus on the unusual-looking line first:

```
val =+ ++i;
```

The operators here are `=` (assignment), `+` (unary plus), and `++` (pre-increment).  There is no `=+` operator.  Java interprets it as two operators: `=` and `+`.  It's clearer with appropriate whitespace added:

```
val = + ++i;
```

Now let's analyze the processing:

First iteration: `val` and `i` are `0`.  `i` is pre-incremented to `1`, and that's the result of `++i`.  The unary `+` does nothing, and `1` is assigned to `val`.  Then the iteration statement `val++` occurs and now `val` is `2`.  `i` is still `1`, so the `for` loop condition is met and a second iteration occurs.

Second iteration: `i` is pre-incremented again, to `2`.  The unary `+` does nothing and `val` is assigned `2`.  The iteration statement `val++` occurs again and it's now `3`.  But `i` is now `2`, and it's not less than `2`, so the `for` loop terminates, and `val` -- `3`- is printed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `=+` operator in Java, according to the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). Use `+=` instead to get desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

if the operator used was `+=` you will be **adding** to `val` the value of `i+1`.

in your case you are **assigning** to val the value of `i+1` each time, 
on the final iteration `i = 2` so `val = 3`.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected calculation:

```
val   i
0     0  i<2 = true;
0     0  ++i;
0     1  val = +i = 1;
1     1  (end of for loop) val++;
2     1  i<2 = true;
2     1  ++i;
2     2  val = +i = 2;
2     2  (end of for loop) val++;
3     2  i<2 = false;
Output: 3
```