# Java Operators, + - what is happening in the below code and why it is written like that

Tags: java, operators

In our java code i have encountred a line which i didnot understand  why
 **total = + - valFromsp;**  or  **total = - + valFromsp;** 
so I wrote small program and attached it here.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main (String... arg) {
        int total =  20;
        int valFromsp = 60 ; 
        total = + - valFromsp;

        System.out.println(total);  // prints -60

    }
}
```

Comment: and what does it print?

Comment: `+` and `-` are unary operators here. This is the same as `total = + (-valFromsp)`.

Comment: @ScaryWombat -60

Comment: [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27371089/3558960)

Comment: and even the same as `total = - + valFromsp;`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Oh that is a nice answer

Comment: @sharief you should [edit] your question to add such pertinent details (I've already done it).

Comment: @AndyTurner got it : -)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It just means this:

```
total = -valFromsp;
```

The line of code is an assignment statement with the right hand side expression being `+ - valFromsp`. What does `+ - valFromsp` mean? If we add brackets, it becomes `+(-(valFromsp))`.

The unary operator `-` operates on the operand `valFromsp` making it `-60`. And then the `+` unary operator operates on `-60` to do nothing to it.

The `+` and `-` unary operators are specified in [§15.15](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15) of the Java language specification:

> The operators +, -, ++, --, ~, !, and the cast operator (§15.16) are
>   called the unary operators.
>
> ```
> UnaryExpression: 
>     PreIncrementExpression 
>     PreDecrementExpression 
>     + UnaryExpression
>     - UnaryExpression 
>     UnaryExpressionNotPlusMinus
> ```

The use of the `+` unary operator is further specified in [§15.15.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.3):

> Unary numeric promotion ([§5.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1)) is performed on the operand. The type of the unary plus expression is the promoted type of the operand. The result of the unary plus expression is not a variable, but a value, even if the result of the operand expression is a variable.

But since you are using `int`s, which does not undergo unary numeric promotion, `+` does nothing. Even if you are using `byte`, `short` or `char`, the `+` will still do nothing, because the `-` unary operator also does promotion. So there really isn't any reason to use both `+` and `-` at the same time.

I suggest you just change it to:

```
total = -valFromsp;
```

to avoid confusion in the future.

Comment: got the clarification now, and thank you every one.

Comment: Previously i donot have enough reputation to accept the answer , and now i got the reputation  to accept  it

Answer (score 0):

let me start explaining this with a simple example, consider

```
total = + valFromsp;
```

> the above line means `total = total + valFromsp;`

similar to this `total = - + valFromsp` means

```
total = - (total + valFromsp);
```

Now you can again further expand this as `total = total - (total + valFromsp)`

> consider below example which gives same output

```
    int total = 10;
    int val = 50;
    //total = - + val; //this is also equals to the below line
    total = total - (total + val);
    System.out.println(total); //output -50.
```

Comment: You are wrong, you seem to be thinking of `+=`. `- + val` is simply equivalent to `-1 * 1 * val`, or `-50`.